# Importing data from Excel File using PHP Excel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to import some data from an excel sheet, but one of my variables (level) isn't working. I was hoping someone could take a look at why this one won't work, but event and division do.

```
class CompetitionClass 
{
   public $event;
   public $division;
   public $level;

   function __construct(){

      $this->entryTable = array();
   }
}



$x++;
$compClass[$x] = new CompetitionClass();
$compClass[$x] -> event = htmlspecialchars((string)$objPHPExcel->getSheet($key)->getCell('F1')->getOldCalculatedValue());
$compClass[$x] -> division = htmlspecialchars((string)$objPHPExcel->getSheet($key)->getCell('H1')->getOldCalculatedValue());
$compClass[$x] -> level = htmlspecialchars((string)$objPHPExcel->getSheet($key)->getCell('F2')->getOldCalculatedValue());



foreach($compClass as $key => $value)
{
   if($value -> division == "MOD")
   {
       print(strtoupper($value -> event)."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ".strtoupper($value -> level)."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ".strtoupper($value -> division)."<BR/>");
   }
```

}

Comment: Looks fine, it's difficult to say anything from this limited information

Comment: @Viney I was able to figure it out

I had to change my readCell function to include row 2 and not just row 1.

Comment: Please put your explanation in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my readCell function to include row 2 and not just row 1.

This is what I had before the change:

```
class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter
{
   public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '')
   {
      if (($row == 1 and in_array($column, range('F','H'))) or ($row >= 3 and $row <= 25 and in_array($column, range('G','N'))))
         { return true; }
      return false;
   }
}
```

This is after the change:

```
class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter
{
   public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '')
   {
      if (($row >= 1 and $row <= 2 and in_array($column, range('F','H'))) or ($row >= 3 and $row <= 25 and in_array($column, range('G','N'))))
         { return true; }
      return false;
   }
}
```

So changing $row == 1 to $row >= 1 and $row <= 2